# Keeping things in a vector invalidates internal references, how to solve?

Tags: c++, struct

I have a struct like this:

```
struct A {
    B b;
    C c;
}
```

Where c keeps a reference to b. I keep A's in a vector:

```
std::vector<A> as;
```

When pushing back new elements into the vector, it may move in memory. This changes the adress of the b's and invalidates the reference that c has to b. Is there any better way to solve this than to move the data of b out of the struct and keep a pointer to it?

Comment: std::deque is what you want

Comment: Implement the Rule Of Three.

Comment: @Dieter: I might even store them in an std::map in the future, though. I don't want to tie myself to a certain container.

Comment: @Gustav Nilsson Than, choose a container, which does not move data around (like vecter)

Answer (score 0):

you may have a copy (move in c++11) constructor in A which initializes C with the correct reference to B.

Edit: Add sample

```
class B { /*stuff*/};
class C {
public:
    explicit C(B& b) : b(&b) {}
private:
    B* b;
};

struct A {
    A() : b(), c(b) {}
    A(const A& rhs) : b(rhs.b), c(b) {
        // Do other needed copy
    }

    B b;
    C c;
};
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm not even sure that it exposes any interface to change that after construction. I hate C++...

Comment: @GustavNilsson - what you have is a bad design. It won't work in **any** language. If you have something **similar** that works in another language, then implement **the same thing** in C++. In particular, if you're coming from Java, then `B b` is not at all what you think it is. Java uses pointers for pretty much everything; to duplicate that stuff, use pointers in C++: `B *b`. Of course, you then have to think about memory management, which, believe it or not, is a good thing!

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I was talking more about conventions in C++. Keeping things on the heap is standard in many other languages, but in C++ you're supposed to keep a smart pointer and stuff. It's just a lot more to think about. How is thinking about manual memory management a good thing?

Comment: Yes, you can't carry designs based on one language to another language without understanding both languages and, usually, enduring some pain.

Comment: @GustavNilsson - having to think about memory management is indeed a massive pain ... until you find something where you _do_ need fine control over memory layout and simply can't do it at all in other languages.

Comment: @Useless: I'm pretty sure I won't need that for this project. Maybe I should switch languages.

Comment: @Useless the thing is, most of the time you don't really have to think that hard about memory management. I have never found it to be a pain at all. Of course, if you complicate things by trying to replicate the idioms of a garbage collected language, then you can easily run into trouble.

Comment: Agreed, and if @GustavNilsson can tell us _what_ this is supposed to achieve, we may be able to suggest a simpler, or more idiomatic, solution.

Answer (score 0):

When the vector reallocates memory, it constructs copies of your objects and destroys the old ones (using the copy or move constructors).

Since A,B,C are no-longer trivially initializable (that reference needs some class-specific logic to set up correctly), you need provide code to do it.

```
struct B {};
struct C {
  B& b_;

  C() = delete; // in C++11, or just declare but don't implement
  explicit C(B& b) : b_(b) {}
};
struct A {
  B b;
  C c;
  A() : c(b) {}
  A(A const &other) : b(other.b), c(b) {}
  A& operator= (A const &other) {
    b=other.b;
    // c already refers to the correct b ...
    return *this;
  }
};
```

Note this C has no members apart from the reference. If your C contains other stuff that *should* be copied/moved/assigned, just leave the reference alone and only modify those members.